# "Statement requires expression of integer type" error with switch statement and array of strings

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Trying to work with array, but it gives me ***"Statement requires expression of integer type('id' invalid)"*** right at switch statement. What's wrong?

```
NSArray count = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", nil];    

switch ([count objectAtIndex: myIndex]) {
    case 1:
        NSLog(@"One");
        break;
    case 2:
        NSLog(@"Two");
        break;
    case 3:
        NSLog(@"Three");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing basic programming knowledge... My advice, start from zero, and don't try to learn everything in a week. Also, don't use tutorials to learn, get a book or go to a class (if possible).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A switch statement only works on integral types.  Your array contains `NSString` objects.  Convert the `NSString` that you get from the array to an integer like this:

```
NSArray count = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", nil];

NSString *obj = [count objectAtIndex: myIndex];
switch ([obj intValue]) {
    case 1:
        NSLog(@"One");
        break;
    case 2:
        NSLog(@"Two");
        break;
    case 3:
        NSLog(@"Three");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: why not store NSNumbers in the array?  It's a bit fragile to store numbers as strings ...

Comment: @bryanmac That would make more sense...but NSNumber is still an object, so you'd still have to extract the integral value to use in the switch statement.

Comment: Quick question: how do you create a Global array, so that it can be accessed from every method?

Comment: "how do you create a Global array, so that it can be accessed from every method?"  Thats a question that at best shows you really really need to take a step back and read a good book on objC dev and at worst will lead you to some horrible code with global values.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating an array of literal NSStrings and doing case statements on ints.  You can only switch on integral types.

The problem is arrayWithObjects creates an array of NSObject derived objects which you can't switch on an object (id).

If you want to store an array of numbers, then one option is to store NSNumber objects rather than relying on the fragility of storing strings that you hope are numbers.  This works:

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], nil];

switch ([[arr objectAtIndex:1] intValue]) {
    case 1:
        NSLog(@"1");
        break;

    case 2:
        NSLog(@"2");
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

It outputs:

```
2012-03-05 23:23:46.798 Craplet[82357:707] 2
```

Comment: I realized that another problem was that I initiated my Array in - (void)viewDidLoad method, but I can't access it from another method. How do you create a global array (global vars in general)?

Comment: Checkout the singleton pattern.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like

Comment: the other thing you can do is delegates (have one view provide a delegate for the other view to call back and get data).  depends whether it's views sharing data or you really want it to be a single global object ...

Answer (score 1):

`[count objectAtIndex:]` returns an Id (aka object), which in your particular case would be a NSString, in either case, its not an int that your case expression is expecting. You'll want `[[count objectAtIndex:myIndex] intValue]` to convert the NSString to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Your array objects are NSStrings, not ints. What is the larger picture here that you're trying to accomplish?

You could:

```
NSString *str = [count objectAtIndex:myIndex];
if ([str isEqualToString:@"1"]) NSLog(@"One");
else if ... // etc
```

Better yet:

```
static NSString *one = @"1";
static NSString *two = @"2";
// etc

NSArray *count = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:one, two, ... nil];

NSString *str = [count objectAtIndex:myIndex];

if (str == one) NSLog(@"One"); // this works because now 'str' and 'one' are the same object
else if ... // etc
```